# Make bootstrap spread evenly and align divs correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know what is happening that when my div is X size, can be seen easily one one screen with out the need of a scroll wheel, it places the footer way below the screen, however, it works when the div is placed or sized bigger

Sample code:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="header cms-logo">
        <h1 class="font header">The Old Thatch Inn</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="container inner clear-top">
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

.container {
margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
background-color: #e7e7e7;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#wrap {
min-height: 100%;
}

#main {
overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
position: relative;
margin-top: -150px;
height: 150px;
clear: both;
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

I have made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcy9n4cg/) to how this works.

Many thanks

Comment: Don't understand the question. Please proofread and be specific about which div you are talking about.

Comment: Apologies, @wazz, I was referring to the `#wrap` div, it sits perfectly with loads of content allowing the footer to be pushed to the bottom of the page at all times, however with little content, the footer does not move up in response to this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#wrap` css or change the percentage on `min-height: 100%;` (smaller).